# Android - Action Bar doesn't show up using Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am trying to use `Theme.AppCompat`, but when I do the Action Bar simply disappear. There is no errors or whatsoever.

The thing is I'm using this exact setting on two more projects and they work just fine, not sure what changed.

I also tried changing support library version, parent theme, cleaning the project, rebuilding and invalidating cache. Wasn't sure if any of that would help but I did anyway.

I am using Android Studio 0.8.14

Correct me if I'm wrong but that's how I use Material Theme widgets and color palette on older API's, right?

Preview

[image]

---

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityLogin"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
}
```

---

Comment: v21 of appcompat uses toolbar not an actionbar, you need to put the toolbar in a view. see this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: @tyczj you definitely don't NEED to put a `Toolbar` in the layout, it is entirely optional. By default `ActionBarActivity` will figure it out for you, but you can override with your own. The implementations changed with v21 from `ActionBarImplVERSION` to `ToolbarActionBar`/`WindowDecorActionBar`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My answer should be as a comment but this is the only way I can reply.
Are you extending **ActionBarActivity** in your activity?
Have you tried the [show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#show%28%29) method in your activity?

Comment: I feel really stupid, I totally forgot to extend **ActionBarActivity**. Good thing you wrote a reply I guess, thanks.

Comment: This answer made me check my theme. It turns out you can use action bar themes to get action bar when you extend Activity.

Comment: If you are using Theme.AppCompat isn't it better to extend AppCompatActivity?